# Contacts Info Rollbacked

Tags: contacts

I have Lumia930 (WP8.1). I change the profile picture and name of some contacts but after some days I connected to Internet via Wi-Fi the contact's name and profile picture are return to the previous state. How can I disable this feature?

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent your contacts from being synced with your Microsoft Account unless you have a different E-Mail Account set up with which your contacts are being associated.

I would recommend to activate your Wifi when editing the contact information so these changes will be saved correctly. You can check this by signing in to [outlook.com](http://outlook.com) with you Microsoft Account (and also make edits there).